# flutter build web: Failed to compile application for the Web

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, web, build

Is there any workaround for this problem?

Dart SDK Version: 2.10.5 (stable)
Flutter Version: 2.0.2 channel stable

Package compatibility issue has passed.

> flutter build web

- Failed to compile application for the Web.

  Target dart2js failed: Exception: lib/main.dart:1:1:
  Error: A library can't opt out of null safety by default, when using sound null safety.
  // @dart=2.9
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^
  ../../Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_analytics_web-0.2.0+1/lib/firebase_analytics_web.dart:1:1:
  Error: A library can't opt out of null safety by default, when using sound null safety.
  // @dart=2.9
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^
  ../../Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_analytics_platform_interface-1.1.0/lib/firebase_analytics_platform_interface.dart:5:1:
  Error: A library can't opt out of null safety by default, when using sound null safety.
  // @dart=2.9
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^
  ../../Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_analytics_platform_interface-1.1.0/lib/method_channel_firebase_analytics.dart:5:1:
  Error: A library can't opt out of null safety by default, when using sound null safety.
  // @dart=2.9
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^
  Error: Cannot run with sound null safety, because the following dependencies
  don't support null safety:

  - package:uuid
  - package:excel
  - package:pretty_qr_code
  - package:qr
  - package:responsive_table
  - package:crypto
  - package:convert
  - package:archive
  - package:xml
  - package:short_uuids
  - package:any_base
  - package:responsive_context
  - package:petitparser